# Creating Columns And Rows On Access Report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-reports

I see in Access 2013 you can set how many columns you want the report to be, but how can you control how many rows are displayed on the report?

I want to generate a report that has a control source of a query and has 10 records from that query per page.  Dispaly like such:

```
Person 1     Person 2
Person 3     Person 4
Person 5     Person 6
Person 7     Person 8
Person 9     Person 10
```

I know you can set the formatting of the report to across then down to get this look, but how can I control that 10 display per page?

Comment: Can you please be more specific on your exact desired result? If you want to print multiple columns on a single page, I can help you with that. I'm currently inclined to mark your question as too broad.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - I want to print 2 columns, but have 5 rows in each column.  I am unclear/uncertain on how to set a fixed amount of rows to appear on each page.

Answer (score 1):

To print multiple columns of a report, you can set the columns option in the page setup. This only changes print preview and prints, not report view.

**Screenshot for Access 2016:**

[image]

Comment: This changes columns - what about number of rows, horizontal on the page?

Comment: That's determined by the amount of rows that fit on a page and how you set up the rest of your report

Comment: That is what I was after.  I must then shrink the amount of data on the report so I get 5 rows on the page.